# How to automatically add paragraph tags in the Visual Editor

Tags: wp-autop

From my Googling, it appears as though the default behavior in Wordpress is to *add* paragraphs automatically, but in the HTML view, regardless of what style I choose in the Visual Editor's style drop-down (paragraph, for example), paragraph tags never appear.  I also do not see `wpautop()` called anywhere in my theme (which I inherited from a now departed developer).

What can I do to set this straight?  Adding `<p>` tags to everything is obviously not going to fly with the content editors.

Answer (score 10):

Paragraph tags are added upon **display**, *not* upon **storage**. The `wpautop()` function is added as a filter to `the_content`.

You won't ever see these added paragraph tags in either the visual or HTML editors.

Comment: Seems a bit silly no?  Paragraphs are, well, paragraphs: why not wrap them in the appropriate markup?

Comment: You're welcome to write a patch to change the behavior, but I doubt it would get implemented. :)

Comment: I'll live with it.  Where abouts would I go to re-enable this?  I just grep'ed through the theme directory for `wpautop` with no results.

Comment: Re-enable *what*, exactly? `wpautop()` is added as a filter to `the_content`, in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`.

Comment: Odd, it's there (`add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop'            );`), but when I create a new page, type a paragraph, add a line break (and highlight the text and choose "paragraph" from the styles, it looks great in the visual editor but when I publish it, there's no paragraph tags wrapping it; this is why I've been adding them manually in the HTML tab.

Comment: Can you show a live example?

Comment: @gravyface I get this same issue while using a (very basic) custom theme, but if I switch back to eg the twenty-twelve theme, paragraphs are rendered correctly.  It's like something in my theme has done a `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop')`... but it isn't there.  I even explicitly added an `add_filter(...)` to no avail.  Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

One solution is to install the [TinyMCE Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/) plugin. In the plugin settings you have a option "Stop removing the `<p>` and `<br />` tags when saving and show Them in the HTML editor".

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are using `the_content` for calling the post content and not something like `get_the_content`. WordPress `wpautop` filter is applied on `the_content`.

Comment: That no makes any difference in the visual editor. Read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I just struggled with this same issue and was about to loose my mind because I tried everything mentioned above and other ideas. It turned out that the client was using a Yootheme, and there is a tick box in the settings of that particular theme, which when clicked solved the issue immediately. Here's a link to the forum post: https://yootheme.com/support/question/4342

In other words, it could be a theme related issue.

Answer (score 0):

[`nl2br()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) can be used to add the line breaks again when using the filtered HTML again

Answer (score -3):

The `wpautop()` filter changes the content view but not changes the view mode on the content editor.

**Example:**
`<?php the_content(); ?>` displays the content normally. If you add `remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');` the content is displayed without `p` tags.

In both cases, the content editor is displayed in the same manner

Comment: That’s what Chip said. What is the point of this answer?

Comment: It was supposed to be a comment, a supplement to the explanation made ​​by Chip Bennett.

Comment: If it was supposed to be a "comment," it should be a **comment**...